# Filter disabled AD users from Organizational chart using Active Directory Import

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, user-profile-service

So pople who are no longer a part of the organization are shown in the Organizational chart on MySites.

I know the solution when the User Profile Synchronization instance is started, and the SharePoint Profile Synchronization settings is on. Then I can create a connection to filter disabled users.

But what if I want to run the new setting, SharePoint Active Direcotry Import, that one does not run with the User Profile Synchronization instance. When I run this setting/connection I cannot filter out disabled users. There a check-box when setting up the connection to filter out disabled users, but that check-box does not do anything.

So what are my solutions?

Do I have to use SharePoint Porfile Synchronization or is there a way to fix it by using the lighter SharePoint Active Directory Import.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “SharePoint Active Directory Import” does not mark the profile to be deleted either with incremental or Full Import when they are disabled and only way to remove the obsolete users is as mentioned [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RemoveObsUsers)

1. Run Full Import
2. Post that run Use SharePoint Management Shell to Run following

   $upa = Get-SPServiceApplication -id

   Set-SPProfileServiceApplication -Identity $upa - PurgeNonImportedObjects $true

[SharePoint 2013 : ADImport is not cleaning up User Profiles in SharePoint whose AD Accounts are disabled .](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2014/04/14/sharepoint-2013-adimport-is-not-cleaning-up-user-profiles-in-sharepoint-whose-ad-accounts-are-disabled.aspx)

Comment: Ok, so the only way is to do it manually via PowerShell. Then my only solution is to run SharePoint Profile Synchronization, if I do not wan to create som kind of extra task to run and delete the disabled users.

Comment: this is the one of 100's limitation of ADI. you can think of schedule task which will every day and clean the disable user otherwise UPA sync will be the best option.

Comment: Great, thanks. I wil go with the UPA synch to start with.

Comment: Hi again. I just tried to run the NoImportObject $true, to se the list of users to be deleted. My service accounts are among them, but it will not affect my services if they are deleted from the Profile Store, right? It is only the profile store the fuction above deletes from.?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the disabled users, “My site clean-up Job” should be enable. We enabled the job and run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Same worked for me as for Upendra Yadav - Here are some more details:

1. Add filter to user profile connection in SharePoint central administration and add [userAccountControll Bin on equals 2](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2011/02/22/323.aspx)

2. Run Full Sync, now you see the userprofiles in the userprofile services in the section of "Missing import profiles" because of the filter
3. Wait for your daily "MySite Cleanup" job or start it manually.
   Then the users who are not imported by full sync are marked for deletion and the mysitecleanup job will delete them. After the deletion of the mysite the wont appear on the organigramm in the Mysites of the users anymore.